# creating cross region S3 VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I don't see a way to create VPC endpoint that can cross region boundary i.e. create an S3 endpoint in `US-East-1` and point it to `US-West-1`.

What is the best way to accomplish this without creating `Cross-Region Replication`?

Comment: What task are you wishing to accomplish? Is it copying objects to a bucket in a different region?

Comment: I want to access the bucket from EC2 without going thru the public internet.

Comment: You could get creative and use VPC Peering, but I don't think you could connect to the VPC Endpoint in the other region. You'd probably need a NAT Gateway there. Connections to S3 are via HTTPS, so traffic encrypted. Is there a particular goal you have in not going through the Internet?

Comment: For compliance and ATO requirements.

Comment: If those requirements allow you to store data in a different region, then it wouldn't be "Data Governance". They would probably accept encrypted communication, which is provided by HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

From [Endpoints for Amazon S3 - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html):

> Endpoints currently do not support cross-Region requests—ensure that you create your endpoint in the same Region as your bucket.

Comment: I understand that. I wanted to see if there is any other way to do it without replacing the objects to the bucket in the region where my EC2 is.

Comment: Could you please clarify that requirement? I'm not sure what you mean by "without replacing the objects".

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I meant without replicating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing proxy solution in your network you can leverage that to circumvent S3 cross-region API calls to go through the proxy for that use-case. Below is the sample code for doing the same using a https proxy,

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(proxies={'https': 'your.proxy:port'}))
```